# Best practices for using Google Apps Mail (GMail) and Outlook via IMAP (Community Wiki)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, google-workspace

I'm looking to collect the best practices for using GMail with Outlook via IMAP.

It seems like out of the box IMAP performance can be an issue with Outlook (vs. Apple Mail, which apparently handles it much better).  Outlook seems to get easily bogged down when syncing IMAP changes, and will often momentarily freeze or report (not responding).

This has been covered a few times on SU, but I thought I'd start a community wiki to bring these best practices together and vote up the best ones.

Answer (score 1):

Via http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/solutions-for-slow-gmail-imap-with-microsoft-outlook/1761/ :

- "Download headers only" for SPAM and TRASH folders
- "Download complete item including attachments" for INBOX and DRAFTS
- Decrease the send/receive interval to 1 minute